# Elasticsearch - Split string into common words without white space or special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been trying to figure out the way to split a string into words using elastic search, i have tried using the **word_delimiter** but it only seems to work if the string is already split for example "this-is-a-string"

However, my goal is to split strings into words like these examples:

```
"redcar" => "Red Car"
"greatholiday" => "Great Holiday"
"myhouseisred" => "My house is red"
```

What would the best option? Would i use a custom tokenizer?

Any help would be a huge relief, Thanks!

--- Use Case ---

@Elasticsearch Ninja

I have a database of documents, one of the columns contains strings specific to that document, however, Some of those strings contains English words and are not correctly formatted (There is no way for me to get a copy of already formatted data because the current format is the only way i can receive the data)

For example i have the following columns:

```
id   |      text        |   document_id
 1         redcar             10844
 2        cheaphouses         22418
 3        notarealstring       9821
 ......
 ......
```

I want to use elastic search or maybe some other solution that can parse each "Text" field and separate the string based on common English words, Therefore the current documents would become:

- Document 1)  Red Car
- Document 2)  Cheap Houses
- Document 3)  NO MATCH <-- Notice this document would probably not return any words because
  the string does not contain common words

Comment: Have you looked into something like the whitespace analyzer/tokenizer? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html

Comment: Yeah it does not seem to be possible with that because the strings do not contain whitespaces or any other special char so for example i cant split on hyphens or full stops, its a case of splitting the string based on common English words i guess... Therefore, redcar would be split into red car

Comment: Oh sorry I see now. This is not how elasticsearch works, it doesn't have a full dictionary build inside. Your only option is to split it before sending it to ES, but I'm pretty sure that will take a looooot of time to build. You'll need to build a dictionary + have all variations of the words. I think it's best to rethink your concept. hope this helps!

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja - Im not sure if accepting as top answer is the best option because it does not solve the issue i have? Maybe i can add some more information regarding my use case which will enable you to provide more help?

Comment: @LinuxNovice as mentioned in comment by other user, it not how ES works and I totally understood your issue, If you want I can modify the answer and add that its not supported by ES and give more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible using any `tokenizer`, or `custom-analyzer` in elasticsearch as you don't have a fixed pattern by which you are dividing your text and creating tokens.

But as mentioned earlier in the comments if you try to do this yourself it will not be the efficient and mostly the wrong way to do that and will be really difficult to cover all the use-cases you might have.

**In-short, ES doesn't provide out of the box solution and you have to build these tokens in your application but it will not be efficient and performant.**

Comment: I've just updated my question, do you think it is not possible to use elasticsearch for my issue?  I did some research and i came across Sphinx Word Breaker but i have not tried this yet... http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/ref-wordbreaker.html

Comment: @LinuxNovice i went through this link in details, and it's really interesting and looks like would serve your use-case better than ES, but having said that, and as I am expert in Elasticsearch(ES) and knows that ES provides great community support and a lot of advance features and is the no 1 search engine in the world for full-text search, not sure sphinxsearch would be able to justify all this.

Comment: @LinuxNovice if your use-case is simple and with less scalable and advanced feature requirements you can go ahead with sphix, but as mentioned earlier you know all your use-cases(present as well as future) so its a trade-off you need to make.